# C - Inaccurate write() position obtained with lseek() when using multiple threads

Tags: c, file-io, pthreads

I'm having a problem getting the correct file position at which I'm writing when simultaneously writing to different parts of the same file using multiple threads.

I have one global file descriptor to the file. In my writing function, I 
first lock a mutex, then do `lseek(global_fd, 0, SEEK_CUR)` to get the current file 
position. I next write 31 zero bytes (31 is my entry size) using `write()`, in effect to reserve space for later. I then unlock the mutex.

Later in the function, I declare a local `fd` variable to the same file, and open 
it. I now do an `lseek` on that local `fd` to get to the position I learned from 
earlier, where my space is reserved. Finally, I `write()` 31 data bytes there for 
the entry, and close the local `fd`.

The issue seems to be that rarely, an entry doesn't get written to the expected location (it's not mangled data - it seems that either it is swapped with a different entry, or two entries were written to the same location). There are multiple threads running that 
"writing function" I described.

I since learned that `pwrite()` can be used to write to a specific offset, which would be more efficient, and eliminate the `lseek()`. However, I first want to find out: what is wrong with my original algorithm? Is there any type of buffering that could be causing the discrepancy between the expected write location, and where the data actually ends up getting stored in the file?

The relevant code snippet is below. The reason this is an issue is that in a second data file, I record the location where the entry I'm writing will be stored. If that location, based on the `lseek()` before the write, is not accurate, my data doesn't match up properly -- which is what happens on occasion (it's hard to reproduce - it happens in maybe 1 in 100k writes). Thanks!

```
db_entry_add(...)
{
   char dbrecord[DB_ENTRY_SIZE];
   int retval;

   pthread_mutex_lock(&db_mutex);

   /* determine the EOF index, at which we will add the log entry */
   off_t ndb_offset = lseek(cfg.curr_fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
   if (ndb_offset == -1)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to determine ndb offset: %s\n", strerror_s(errno, ebuf, sizeof(ebuf)));
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&db_mutex);
      return 0;
   }

   /* reserve entry-size bytes at the location, at which we will
      later add the log entry */
   memset(dbrecord, 0, sizeof(dbrecord));

   /* note: db_write() is a write() loop */ 
   if (db_write(cfg.curr_fd, (char *) &dbrecord, DB_ENTRY_SIZE) < 0)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "db_entry_add2db - db_write failed!");
      close(curr_fd);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&db_mutex);

      return 0;
   }

   pthread_mutex_unlock(&db_mutex);

   /* in another data file, we now record that the entry we're going to write 
      will be at the specified location. if it's not (which is the problem,
      on rare occasion), our data will be inconsistent */ 
   advertise_entry_location(ndb_offset);
   ...

   /* open the data file */
   int write_fd = open(path, O_CREAT|O_LARGEFILE|O_WRONLY, 0644);
   if (write_fd < 0)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: Unable to open file %s: %s\n", __func__, cfg.curr_silo_db_path, strerror_s(errno, ebuf, sizeof(ebuf)));
      return 0;
   }

   pthread_mutex_lock(&db_mutex);

   /* seek to our reserved write location */
   if (lseek(write_fd, ndb_offset, SEEK_SET) == -1)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s: lseek failed: %s\n", __func__, strerror_s(errno, ebuf, sizeof(ebuf)));
      close(write_fd);
      return 0;
   }

   pthread_mutex_unlock(&db_mutex);

   /* write the entry */
   /* note: db_write_with_mutex is a write() loop wrapped with db_mutex lock and unlock */ 
   if (db_write_with_mutex(write_fd, (char *) &dbrecord, DB_ENTRY_SIZE) < 0)
   {
      fprintf(stderr, "db_entry_add2db - db_write failed!");         
      close(write_fd);

      return 0;
   }

   /* close the data file */
   close(write_fd);

   return 1; 
}
```

One more note, for completeness. I have a similar but simpler routine that could also be causing the problem. This one uses buffered output `(FILE*, fopen, fwrite)`, but performs an `fflush()` at the end of each write. It writes to a *different file* than the earlier routine, but could cause the same symptom.

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&data_mutex);

/* determine the offset at which the data will be written. this has to be accurate,    
otherwise it could be causing the problem */ 
offset = ftell(current_fp);

fwrite(data);
fflush(current_fp);

pthread_mutex_unlock(&data_mutex);
```

Comment: deleted my answer, you are right, that's not it.

Comment: You should probably be consistent in the use of `sizeof(dbrecord)` vs `DB_ENTRY_SIZE` in the code.  However, that has nothing to do with synchronization between threads.

Comment: You probably don't want the `O_CREAT` in `int write_fd = open(path, O_CREAT|O_LARGEFILE|O_WRONLY, 0644);` because if the file has vanished, you have big problems, do you not?

Comment: Your `lseek()` error handling path does not unlock the mutex; if it ever gets activated, everything is going to be blocked on the mutex, which will never be unlocked.

Comment: If `db_write` fails, you are closing a separate file descriptor (`curr_fd` is not `cfg.curr_fd`), which is presumably a transcription/simplification error.  You are also not marking the file as closed, so if it is ever activated, you are likely to be getting a lot of EBADF errors after the failure.

Comment: I agree with Richard and Bdonlan that the problem is likely in the interworking of standard I/O and file descriptor I/O.  However, could there be any issue with `advertise_entry_location()`?  You mention it in passing, but it is the overlooked that often causes the trouble?

Comment: Why do you unlock the mutex before the call to `advertise_entry_location(ndb_offset)`?  If you have multiple threads writing to that file, you've given the other threads a chance to run and change the unlocking threads environment.  Does your code ever check the return vals from the mutex calls?

Comment: You should probably try creating an isolated test case that does nothing but create a large number of threads continuously writing dummy updates - if you can demonstrate the problem with the test case, you could include it here.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be several places where things could go wrong.  I would make the following changes: (1) be consistent and use the same I/O library as per bdonlan's suggestion, (2) make the lseek() and the writes an atomic action guarded by a mutex so that only a single thread at a time can do those actions of adding to both files.  SEEK_CUR does a seek based on the current location of the file offset pointer so would you not want SEEK_END to seek to the end of the file in order to append there?  Then if you are modifying a particular section of the file you would use SEEK_SET to reposition to the location you want to write to.  And you would want to do this in a mutex guarded section so as to allow only a single thread to do the file positioning and file update.

Comment: For #1, the two routines are writing to different files, so I don't think using different I/O types is an issue. For #2, the lseek and the write on the global file descriptor is indeed atomic/protected by a mutex, as shown. I don't understand why the seek/write to the local variable file descriptor would need to be atomic. Other threads are writing to the file, but they should never be writing to the same location. The SEEK_CUR  is to get the current file position. I then perform a write, and assume that the data will get written starting at that current file position - O_APPEND is being used.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using your 'simpler routine' at the same time, this could indeed be a problem. If these are separate file descriptors, there's nothing to ensure that they're both pointing at the end of the file at all times (unless you use append mode, however I'm not sure what the semantics around ftell for append mode are). If they're the same fd (ie, you have a raw fd and a `FILE *` pointing to the same place), you might have problems with the standard library getting confused about where you are in a file, when you use `write()` to bypass it.

Comment: The 'simpler routine' is writing to a different file altogether (and it is also multithreaded). I posted it because it could cause the same symptom, so I'm not sure which routine has the issue.